# Multiple definition of function in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a function for my current project.

Right now, I have a Countries.h header.

When I try to compile this is the error that I get:

```
CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/Countries.c.o: In function `addCountry':
/home/ise/CLionProjects/untitled2/Countries.c:36: multiple definition of `addCountry'
```

This is part of the code:

Countris.h :

```
typedef struct Country Country;
typedef struct City City;
typedef struct Cordinate Cordinate;
//add country
Country* addCountry(char *name1, Cordinate cr1, Cordinate cr2);
```

Countris.c :

```
#include "Countries.h"
#include <stdio.h>
Country* addCountry(char *name1 , Cordinate cr1 , Cordinate cr2) {
    Country *country1 = (Country*)malloc(sizeof(Country));

.. rest of the code

    return country1;
}
```

Comment: Do you define (implement) the function in the header file? Can you perhaps  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: sori , I will try to be more accurate.

Countris.h :
typedef struct Country Country;
typedef struct City City;
typedef struct Cordinate Cordinate;

//add country
Country* addCountry(char *name1, Cordinate cr1, Cordinate cr2);


Countris.c :

Comment: edit your question with code snippets - it won't format properly in a comment

Comment: Please ***edit your question***. There's a link just below the `c` tag.

Comment: sori , I will try to be more accurate.
Countris.h :
typedef struct Country Country;
typedef struct City City;
typedef struct Cordinate Cordinate;
//add country
Country* addCountry(char *name1, Cordinate cr1, Cordinate cr2);
Countris.c :
#include "Countries.h"
#include <stdio.h>
Country* addCountry(char *name1 , Cordinate cr1 , Cordinate cr2) {
    Country *country1 = (Country*)malloc(sizeof(Country));

.. rest of the code

    return country1;
}

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer people can be. Do **not** post code as a comment, instead edit your question and add the code there, as a code block or snippet. Please read the help pages if you're having trouble.

Comment: The number after the file name in the error message is the line number the error happened in. What is on the 36th line of Countries.c?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you compile the source code for `Countries.c` twice. I think you include somewhere in your code `Countries.c` so that is the reason of the error.